# Guice throwing NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, guice, nosuchmethoderror

I am using Guice version 5.1.0 for my project (jdk version 17)

Error Message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.ClassLoader com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.getClassLoader(java.lang.Class)'
    at com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider2.<init>(FactoryProvider2.java:329)
    at com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryModuleBuilder$1.configure(FactoryModuleBuilder.java:334)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:409)
    at com.cs.selfServe.guice.SelfServePagesModule.configure(SelfServePagesModule.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:409)
    at com.google.inject.util.Modules$CombinedModule.configure(Modules.java:157)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:409)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:160)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:78)
    at com.netflix.governator.LifecycleInjectorCreator.createInjector(LifecycleInjectorCreator.java:100)
    at com.netflix.governator.LifecycleInjectorCreator.createInjector(LifecycleInjectorCreator.java:38)
    at com.netflix.governator.InjectorBuilder.createInjector(InjectorBuilder.java:209)
    at com.netflix.governator.InjectorBuilder.createInjector(InjectorBuilder.java:223)
    at com.cs.platform.PlatformApplication$1.create(PlatformApplication.java:131)
    at com.hubspot.dropwizard.guicier.GuiceBundle.run(GuiceBundle.java:102)
    at com.hubspot.dropwizard.guicier.GuiceBundle.run(GuiceBundle.java:33)
    at io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap.run(Bootstrap.java:200)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:42)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:87)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
    at com.cs.platform.PlatformApplication.main(PlatformApplication.java:113)
```

I cant decrease the Guice version below 5 as it is not compatible with jdk 17.
How can I resolve the error?

Comment: If I recall correctly, assisted inject is a separate dependency, right? Check that you are using a compatible version. It looks like assisted inject is calling API that was removed in Guice 5.

Comment: Thanks @Jorn. It worked by updating its version